# how can i extract numbers from a 1D numpy array by a condition?

Tags: python, numpy

```
my_array = np.logspace(-1, 2, num=500)
num = 0.9
```

I want to extract (for example) 30 elements from an array around `num`
Expected result:

```
[0.73405984,   0.74429223,   0.75466726,   0.76518692,
 0.77585321,   0.78666818,   0.79763391,   0.80875249,
 0.82002606,   0.83145678,   0.84304684,   0.85479845,
 0.86671388,   0.8787954 ,   0.89104533,   0.90346602,
 0.91605985,   0.92882923,   0.9417766 ,   0.95490446,
 0.96821531,   0.9817117 ,   0.99539623,   1.00927151,
 1.02334021,   1.03760502,   1.05206867,   1.06673394,
 1.08160363,   1.0966806]
```

I understand that i can use cycle with a condition (for...).
Is there any built-in function?

Comment: [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) set your tolerance and now use the output in boolean indexing.

Comment: thank you!  for 15 values it will be:
`dot_range = my_array[np.isclose(my_array, 0.9, rtol=0.05, atol=0.05)]`

is there any logic to calculate proper `rtol` and `atol` ? For example if array will be 100000 numbers and i need to extract 855 values? Here i done it by manual search...